# Edit profile button not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, routes, url-routing

Just started learning ruby so sorry in advance for any stupid mistakes. Anyways, whenever I am trying to logging in as a 'customer', following is the error which is being generated because of 'Update' button in customer profile.

**cust_profile.rb**

```
class CustProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  enum role: [:customer, :cook, :admin]
  # after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  has_attached_file :photo

  validates_attachment_presence :photo
  validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 1.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :customer
  end

  has_one :cook_profile, required: false
  has_one :cust_profile, required: false

end
```

**cust_home.html**

```
<h1>Customer Profile</h1>
<%= link_to 'Update',  edit_cust_profile_path(current_user.cust_profile) %>

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="row pannel">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwQzkGr6zOpQD7nG8YtZIIzlutO7kOL1NkG88BOH5fNVBqkwWc" class="img-thumbnail picture hidden-xs" />
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwQzkGr6zOpQD7nG8YtZIIzlutO7kOL1NkG88BOH5fNVBqkwWc" class="img-thumbnail visible-xs picture_mob" />
            <div class="header">
              <h2>Customer name</h2>
              <%= @user.cust_profile.name %>
              <h2>Location</h2>
            <%= @user.cust_profile.location %>
    <div class='bookings_buttons' style="float: left; margin-top: 75px">
        <button type="button" onclick="alert('No current bookings!')">View Current Booking</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="alert('No previous bookings!')">View Previous Bookings</button>
    </div>
    <div class='cook_buttons'>
        <button type="button" onclick="alert('This feature is not available yet!')">Book a cook</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="alert('This feature is not available yet!')">Rate a cook</button>
    </div>
```

**cust_profile.html**

```
<div class="page-header text-center">
  <h1>My Profile</h1>
  <%= link_to 'Back to Home Page',  root_path %>
</div>

<h2>User Credentials</h2>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Photo</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= image_tag @user.photo.url, :size => "100x100" %></td>
    <td><%= @user.email %></td>
    <td><%= @user.encrypted_password %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Update',  edit_user_registration_path %></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<% if (@user.cust_profile == nil) then %>
<%= link_to 'Create Profile',  new_cust_profile_path, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<br><br>
<% else %>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @user.cust_profile.name %></td>
    <td><%= @user.cust_profile.location %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Update',  edit_cust_profile_path(@user.cust_profile) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<% end if %>
```

**cust_profiles_controller.rb**

```
class CustProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cust_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /cust_profiles
  # GET /cust_profiles.json
  def index
    @cust_profiles = CustProfile.all
  end

  # GET /cust_profiles/1
  # GET /cust_profiles/1.json
  def show
    @cust_profile = CustProfile.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /cust_profiles/new
  def new
    @cust_profile = CustProfile.new
  end

  # GET /cust_profiles/1/edit
  def edit
    @cust_profile = CustProfile.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /cust_profiles
  # POST /cust_profiles.json
  def create
   @cust_profile = CustProfile.new(cust_profile_params)
   @cust_profile.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cust_profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cust_profile, notice: 'Customer profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cust_profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cust_profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cust_profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cust_profiles/1.json
  def update
    @cust_profile = CustProfile.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cust_profile.update(cust_profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cust_profile, notice: 'Customer profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cust_profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cust_profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cust_profiles/1
  # DELETE /cust_profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @cust_profile = CustProfile.find(params[:id])

    @cust_profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cust_profiles_url, notice: 'Customer profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    def set_profile
      @cust_profile = current_user.cust_profile
    end

    def set_cust_profile
      @cust_profile = CustProfile.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cust_profile_params
      params.require(:cust_profile).permit(:name, :location)
    end
end
```

**easy_controller.rb**

```
class EasyController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if user_signed_in?
      @user = current_user

      if current_user.cook?
        render :cook_home
      end
      if current_user.customer?
        render :cust_home
      end
      if current_user.admin?
        render :admin_home
      end
    end        
  end

  def profile
    if user_signed_in?
      @user = current_user

      if current_user.cook?
        render :cook_profile
      else if current_user.cust?
    render :cust_profile
    end
    end
  end

  def cust_home
      @user = current_user
      if current_user.cust?
          render :cust_home
      end
  end
end
end
```

Following is the error being generated when because of 'update' button in my cust_home.html page

**ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Easy#home**

**No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"cust_profiles", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]**

I suspect the error is coming from my controller but cant quite figure out how to proceed.

**Edit**

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :cuisines
  resources :cook_profiles
  resources :cust_profiles
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  #----- Home routes
  get 'home', to: 'easy#home', as: 'easy_home'
  get 'cook_home', to: 'easy#cook_home', as: 'cook_home'
  get 'cust_home', to: 'easy#cust_home', as: 'cust_home'
  get 'admin_home', to: 'easy#admin_home', as: 'admin_home'
  root to: 'easy#home'

  #----- Route to user-appropriate profile page
  get '/profile', to: 'easy#profile', as: 'profile'

end
```

Comment: add `routes` file in the question .

Answer (score 0):

The error is not caused by the `Update` button. It comes from:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Easy#home
```

So, you have to check the view for `EasyController#home`. When you take a look at it (`cust_home.html`), there is only one place that can cause this issue:

```
<%= link_to 'Update',  edit_cust_profile_path(current_user.cust_profile) %>
```

Since it says:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"cust_profiles", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

probably `current_user.cust_profile` is `nil`.

Comment: How do I go about changing current_user.cust_profile ?

Comment: Let's assume that you are editing user where the ID is eqal `3`. Run rails console (`rails c`) and check if the user with that ID has any cust_profile (`User.find(3).cust_profile`).

In general, you have `has_one :cust_profile, required: false` but you require it (in your HTML if it's `nil` then the code will throw an exception)